# Textview that stays as narrow as possible, but grows to wrap content

Tags: android, xml

edited to clarify:

I have a TextView that defaults to 150dp in width, full height.  I'm populating it with a string that varies in length.  Sometimes the string is short enough that it doesn't fill up the given size of TextView, but other times it's larger than the default size.  If the text won't fit in the textbox, I want the width of the box to grow to accommodate it, but I'd like it to default to be 150dp wide.  Any suggestions?

```
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/address"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:minWidth="150dp" 
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="18sp" />
```

This creates a textbox that cannot be resized to fit overlong text.

Changing the width to

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

just tries to create a textbox wide enough for the whole message.

The message is generally between 75 and 150 characters.

To sum up: i'm trying to create a textbox that is either 150 dp wide, or just wide enough to fit the entire message, whichever is greater.

Comment: I don't understand why you can't just use android:layout_width="wrap_content"?

Comment: because the text doesn't wrap to the next line until it hits a "hard" barrier.  The box is tall and narrow, and I want it to stay as narrow as possible while still fitting all of the text.  If I tell it to wrap content, the text won't wrap to the next line until the box is at its maximum width.

Comment: so you want it to wrap before it needs to wrap?

Comment: well, sort of.  I want the text to wrap so that it's in a narrow column, defaulting to 150 dp wide.  But, I want the column width to increase if it cannot fit the entire string.

Comment: how will it know when it should increase, and when it shouldn't?

Comment: exactly my conundrum.  I'm guessing that I'll have to check the string size and increase the width programmatically whenever putting in a new string.

Comment: if you were going to do that, perhaps a custom widget would be the right approach, that way you could Override setText(), and check the string length there, and change either the maxWidth or layout_width ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the `Textview` inside a `layout` with a fixed width.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/address"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This will make the textview take the width upto the layout width or less. If it is more length then it will take a new line.

Use `android:gravity="center"` for the layout, if neccesary to make the textview be in the center.

Hope you were looking out for this.

Comment: This is another way to ensure that the text box will not get wider than 150 dp, but I'm looking for a box that is 150dp wide at minimum, but can get wider if needed.  How do I grow the box if the 150dp width isn't big enough to fit the whole string?